# eiffel: semantic of ANY default

Tags: eiffel

Surprised that Default in class `ANY` is **frozen** and **without implementation**???, what is the semantic for this function??

### Class ANY

```
frozen default: detachable like Current
        -- Default value of object's type
    do
    end
```

My intention was to define a `default: like Current` or maybe detachable which returns the default value for current `Class`, so **redefine** it...

Comment: Please try to make your questions more relevant: `ANY` is not a "function", but a "class", representing *any* object. So it's not a convenience class to add features to other classes (which would in fact break those, most likely).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a default value of a detachable version of a type. For reference types, this is `Void`. For expanded types, this is the corresponding default value, i.e. the one initialized with `default_create`. E.g., for `BOOLEAN`, it is `False`.

If an expanded class provides a specific implementation of `default_create`, it is used to initialize `Result` even without a body in `default`. For example, consider a class

```
expanded class X inherit ANY redefine default_create end feature
    item: INTEGER_32
    default_create do item := 42 end
end
```

For a variable `x` of type `X`, an expression `x.default.item` would give 42. When `default` is called, the value of `Result` is initialized by calling `X.default_create` that sets `item`. So, no instructions in the body of `default` are required.

To summarize, `default` returns

- `Void` for reference types;
- a default value for expanded types that do not redefine `default_create`, including basic types: `False`, `0`, `0.0`, etc. If an expanded type has nested attributes, they are initialized recursively using the same rule.
- a value obtained by calling `default_create` otherwise.

Comment: Nice explanation many thx. Recomendations: point out a documentation where what you say can be read, maybe a clearer comment into ANY Class